# Regular expression to select only the words surrounded by Special Characters

Tags: ios, objective-c, regex

I want to write a function which takes a string and changes the color of all words within special characters. For example:

> This is a [Sample] String containing [sample words]

I want to change the font of `[Sample]` and `[sample words]` in the above string because these both are surrounded by special character `[ ]`.

I have tried to make the function using:

```
NSMutableAttributedString * string = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]initWithString:_txtPostDiscussion.text];

NSArray *words=[_txtPostDiscussion.text componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
for (NSString *word in words) {
    if ([word hasPrefix:@"["] && [word hasSuffix:@"]"] ) {
        NSRange range=[_txtPostDiscussion.text rangeOfString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",pre,suf]];
        [string addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor colorWithRed:107.0/255.0 green:148.0/255.0 blue:187.0/255.0 alpha:1.0] range:range];

        [_txtPostDiscussion setAttributedText:string];
    }
}
```

I have also tried to use Regex to get all words inside specific special characters but I am unable to make such regular expression.

Comment: This would probably be easier with an `NSScanner`.

Comment: The regex might be `"\\w+(?=[^\\[\\]]*])"` (if the brackets are always well-balanced).

Comment: Here is another regex, [`(\G(?!\A)\s+|\[)([^\s\]\[]+)`](https://regex101.com/r/LOe3wc/1), that you may utilize, but you will have to concat Group 1 and modified Group 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to match `[Sample maybe some _special_ *things* here]`, we first need to find starting `[`. This bracket has a special meaning for regexes, so inside a regex it must be "decorated" (escaped) with a backslash like so: `\[`. In addition the backslash `\` itself has a special meaning in Objective-C strings, so it must be escaped as well with a 2nd backslash and written like so: `@"\\["`. Alternatively you could use `escapedPatternForString` method to do this escaping for you.

```
NSString *openTagPattern = [NSRegularExpression escapedPatternForString:@"["];
NSString *closeTagPattern = [NSRegularExpression escapedPatternForString:@"]"];
```

Then we want to find several different characters until the end bracket. The statement "any character except x" is encoded by `[^x]`, so any character except the ending bracket is encoded by `[^\]]`. That bracket char is again escaped to be treated literally, and in Objective-C strings you would write `@"[^\\]]"`. Because we want to find 1 or more of such characters, we add `+`:

```
NSString *tagTextPattern = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"[^%@]+", closeTagPattern];
```

Finally we need to have a closing bracket. The final regex just combines these 3 patterns sequentially:

```
NSString *pattern = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@",
    openTagPattern,
    tagTextPattern,
    closeTagPattern];
```

Then you can create an NSRegularExpression instance and call enumerateMatchesInString or matchesInString to give you all the matches. Each match is an NSTextCheckingResult object, which has a `range` property to add an attribute to the original attributed string.

If you knew that the tag text is limited to only letters, digits and underscores, the `tagTextPattern` could be simplified to just `\w+`, i.e. "one ore more word characters", or if we want to allow spaces, tabs (`\s`) the pattern would be `[\w\s]+`, i.e. "one ore more word or whitespace characters" (don't forget to escape them properly).

A common mistake would be to try an expression `\[.+\]`, i.e. "open bracket", "one more more of any character" and "closing bracket". This wouldn't work, because the matching algorithm is greedy (the longer the match - the better), and for the `.+` subpart it would actually eat up the closing bracket as well, and everything else after the tag (text that follows `]`), and potentially join several tags into a huge single tag, or maybe not be able to match the last `]` at the end.

Answer (score 1):

How about searching for balanced brackets as Wiktor suggested?

Here is another pattern that achieves just that:

```
(\[(?>[^\[\]]+|(?1))*\])
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/64IyZo/1)

I cannot test this end-to-end but it should doable using [NSRegularExpression](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsregularexpression).